# Сhecking the photo link

Tags: flutter, api, dart, photo

I used the api to get the url of the image. There is a chance that I will get a broken link and the image won't load. I want a placeholder instead of a broken link. How should I implement this check?

Comment: have you tried error builder inside the image widget?

Comment: you can also use cachednetworkimage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out this package: https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image

```
dependencies:
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.2
```

This way, **CachedNetworkImage** will throw an error in every initial state, as the URL string is always empty or broken. And when the URL is available, the **CachedNetworkImage** will load the image.